# JavaFX white-screen: No content showing in Pane on Run

Tags: java, javafx

I was working just fine on my JavaFX project till I installed netbeans-7.4beta-windows this morning. I then uninstalled it and tried to revert back to netbeans-7.2.1-ml-windows since 7.4beta was showing me code errors I wasn't getting with 7.2.1.

Now, unfortunately, when I try to run my project, I very sadly get the following pop-up error:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError:
com.sun.deploy.config.WinPlatformUserHome()Ljava/lang/String;
```

When I click on "OK" my project window shows, but with nothing but a white window: no borders, just nothing. Not even the text and forms I coded in.

What could be the problem. Will trully appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has something to do with the way JavaFX builds projects. If you look at the [bug report here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226431), it discusses the same problem that you *maybe* having.

Try creating a new project, move all the files over to the new project and run it.

*Have you tried refreshing your current project?*

Comment: Refreshing does nothing. Neither does creating a new project and moving the files there. Thanks for looking at my question and the reply though

Comment: Move it to a new project, refresh and run. Plus, is it possible to switch to `Eclipse` ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Little Child. However, I have had the same problem in the past. Create a new Netbeans project (or javafx project), transfer all the class files on to it, delete the original. Build the new project and it should work!